# Php function displays randomly at top of page

Tags: php, joomla

This may be something someone has already asked so sorry in advance, i'm having a real issue displaying a function in the correct spot.

Background: The site is built on joomla 3.0 and i'm adding some new options to a controller that a smarty template file pulls information from.

My issue is when I run the following function, it is display 100$ correctly as i'd like, but it's displaying at the top of the page (yes it's in the right place in the smarty file).

So......

```
 function getboxsize($cfg, $key, $boxvalues)
        {

            echo '<select name="box_size">';
              foreach($cfg->box_size_options AS $key=>$boxvalues)   
              {
              echo '<option value="'.$boxvalues.'">'.$boxvalues.'</option>';
              }
            echo '</select>';
        }


  // This displays the function in the SMARTY .tpl file
  $lists['shipping_input'] = getboxsize($cfg, $key, $boxvalues);
```

Everything is displayed correctly, with all of the correct options loading in the correct place in the select list, it's just displaying at the top the page and not next to the title of it's spot in the form. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is echoing things out straight away. I suspect you just want to return the output instead:

```
function getboxsize($cfg, $key, $boxvalues) {

    $output = '<select name="box_size">';
    foreach ($cfg->box_size_options AS $key => $boxvalues) {
        $output .= '<option value="' . $boxvalues . '">' . $boxvalues . '</option>';
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY!!!! --- do you know where I might be able to find documentation for this. I was trying to find this answer somewhere online but know where does it display that you must set the output of a function to a variable and then echo the variable inside the function, AND THEN return the function. This is something that is very basic but for some reason isn't talked about much. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure where to find such documentation. But like you say, it is very basic. You're only supposed to output content from within the template.